# Why Are These Angular Divs Not Stretching Vertically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, flexbox

I'm having a lot of trouble getting my angular 1.4 divs to fill the entire page. I've googled "how to stretch content vertically" and have found a lot of answers, but none of them actually work for me. I thought flexbox would be a good thing to use with all the hype around it, but I can't even get a div to fill the page. smh. Here's the code I'm currently using taken right from the angular docs:

```
<div layout="row" layout-sm="column" class="lightblue">
  <div flex>
    I'm above on mobile, and to the left on larger devices.
  </div>
  <div flex>
    I'm below on mobile, and to the right on larger devices.
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's what it looks like:

[image]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how I can get these containers to stretch to fill the entire page? I started this project from the yeoman generator angular-gulp, and this code above is the only thing in my main.html file. thanks, jim.

Comment: Have you tried setting a height for the flex container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The children are stretching. You need to add height to parent.

```js
angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial']);
```

```css
.lightblue {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="BlankApp">
  <div layout="row" layout-sm="column" class="lightblue">
    <div flex>
      I'm above on mobile, and to the left on larger devices.
    </div>
    <div flex>
      I'm below on mobile, and to the right on larger devices.
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```